# RedirectToAction is not working while authentication of mvc3 form with jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

i have been facing an issue in my loginscreen of my application which is developed with mvc3 and jquery, as i am writing the code for checking login credentials in controller and and that controller event is firing by clciking the buttoon click which is developed using jquery. i would like to navigate someo other page('/Customer/CollaborationPortal') when the login credentials are correct, else i want display message box stating that "credentials are wrong" and this is my code.

**JQuery Code**

```js
$("#btnGo").click(function (e) {
                   var RegData = getRegData();
                if (RegData === null) {
                    console.log("Specify Data!");
                    return;
                }

                $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: '/Registration/IsLoginExsit',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: JSON.stringify(RegData),
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            success: function (response) {
                              //window.location.href('/Customer/CollaborationPortal');
                                  Console.Log("success");
                                error: function () {
                                    //aler('Login error');
                                  Console.Log("error");
                                }
                            }



                        });
            });
            function getRegData() {

                var UserName = $("#txtUserName").val();
                var Password = $("#txtPassword").val();
                return { "UserName": UserName, "Password": Password };
            }

        });
```

**Controller  Code**

```cs
public ActionResult IsLoginExsit(BAMasterCustomerDO loginData)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginData.UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty   (loginData.Password))
      {

         bool result = Businesss.Factory.BusinessFactory.GetRegistration().IsLoginExist(loginData.UserName, loginData.Password);
                if (result)
                {
                      System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"]=loginData.UserName;
                       return RedirectToAction("/Customer/CollaborationPortal");


                  }
                  else
                  {                   

                      ViewData["message"] = "Registration failed";
                       return View();
                   }
        }

        return View();

    }
```

and also it is not entering into "success" and "error" code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you have specified the error callback inside success callback, move it  outside like:

```
$.ajax(
{
url: '/Registration/IsLoginExsit',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: JSON.stringify(RegData),
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
success: function (response) {
//window.location.href('/Customer/CollaborationPortal');
console.log("success");
},
error: function () {
//alert('Login error');
console.log("error");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have error function inside of success function....

This it's what you must have:

```
$.ajax(
    {
    url: '/Registration/IsLoginExsit',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(RegData),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (response) {
        //window.location.href('/Customer/CollaborationPortal');
        Console.Log("success");
    },
    error: function () {
        //aler('Login error');
        Console.Log("error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd return a JSON object to the client like this:

Success:

```
{
    'error' : false,
    'redirect' : '/Customer/CollaborationPortal',
    'message' : ''
}
```

Error:

```
{
    'error' : true,
    'redirect' : false,
    'message' : 'Please do this or that'
}
```

My jQuery would be:

```
            $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: '/Registration/IsLoginExsit',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: JSON.stringify(RegData),
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        success: function (response) {
                            if (response.error)
                            {
                                alert(response.message);
                                return;
                            }
                            window.location.pathname = response.redirect;
                        }
                    });
```